# What type of relation represents a function with two argument?

Tags: functions, relations

It is clear to me that functions are relations, where a function $f(x) = y$ can be represented by a relation $xRy$.

What about functions with two arguments? For example $f(x,y)=z$. I know that we cannot treat this as $(x,y)Rz$, as we are not sure if $(x,y)$ actually is a relation or not. If there is such definition, how can I interpret some of the properties of relations such as symmetry, reflexive and transitivity?

Comment: Why can’t you treat it as a binary relation between ordered pairs (the arguments) and singletons (the function values)?

Comment: That is actually how the literature has done it. For example in the case of symmetry, just move every argument around. However, in my mind, symmetry is something like (a,b,c) => (b,a,c), and not other permutations.

Comment: Also, the function’s domain determines whether or not $xR'y$ ($R\ne R'$, obviously). I don’t see the difficulty here. Perhaps you should be more specific in your question.

Comment: In pure set-theoretic terms, a function *is* a relation. Symmetry in the function’s arguments is a rather different thing from symmetry in this relation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a 3-place relation. The infix notation $(x,y)Rz$ is very awkward though, so typically we use something like $R(x,y,z)$

Comment: Okay, then how can I interpret the properties of this relation? For example transitivity?

Comment: Thanks, I found such definitions for a ternary relationship here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_equivalence_relation

Comment: @orezvani Oh, would you look at that! I learned something too then, thanks! :)

Comment: @Bram28  wwhy can t i cancel tis?

Answer (score 0):

If the domain of the function is $X_1 \times X_2$ and the range is $Y$, then a function $f : X_1 \times X_2 \rightarrow Y$ is simply a relation $R$ that is a subset of $(X_1 \times X_2) \times Y$. Hence you get a relation between pairs $(x_1,x_2) \in X_1 \times X_2$ and values $y \in Y$.

More generally, functions of $n$ variables can be seen as subsets of $(X_1 \times X_2 \times \dots \times X_n) \times Y$.